# youtube-dl with Lynda.com through organization login

Tags: youtube-dl

I there any way to download videos from Lynda.com with an oranization account using `youtube-dl`? The command `youtube-dl -u abc@abc.com <link>` won't work because the login is taking place through the organization, and then is being redirected back to Lynda.com. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Firefox add-on named "Cookie Exporter 1.5.1-signed" by fliwatüt to export the cookies file once you're logged into the organization in the browser. Then use that cookie file with the `--cookies` parameter. Check [this](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5926) Github issue for more information.

Comment: This works only for public videos and not for member only videos. Cookies are not working for organization login.